# Using ArrayList to Store Class which Extends Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a driver class called `Advantech` which is stored inside an `ArrayList`. I instantiate and `initialize` my class. The `Advantech` class `extends` `Thread` and the `Advantech` class has a `run()` method. The thread is started within the class once it makes the connection to the device. (`this.start();`)

Is it possible to start the `thread` then store the instance of that class into an `ArrayList`?

When I instantiate the class and store it back into the array list (overwriting the previous position) with `set(pos, class)`, I get `NullPointerException` when I call `class.isAlive()`.

Are there any alternatives/better ways to do this?

I know this may sound strange, but I am using `ArrayList` because otherwise I have to create **eight** classes to start **eight** threads, for example:

```
Advantech adv1;
Advantech adv2;
Advantech adv3;
Advantech adv4;
```

All the parameters are the same for each instance.

Code:

```
private ArrayList<Advantech> advantech = null;
private Advantech adv = null;
....

adv = new Advantech(/* parameters */);

adv.initialize();

advantech.set(0, adv);
```

In Advantech.java:

```
public class Advantech extends Thread {

    ....
    public void run() {

         while(!done) { // do some work }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is stoping you? I mean, yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Marcelo: Silly question. I get NullPointerException. Please read it again. That's why I am asking how to do it right.

Comment: Please post some code; this should work.

Comment: You should post your code where you call `isAlive`.  I suspect you are calling it from another thread, in which case you should use some concurrent list instead of a plain ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've missed something (or you just haven't posted it), you don't seem to have constructed your `ArrayList<Advantech>` anywhere. You need this line before using it:

```
// Here, numOfThreads is an int variable that specifies how many threads you want to store
advantech = new ArrayList<Advantech>(numOfThreads);
```

Also, you might want to rename the list to something more descriptive (maybe `advantechThreadList`.)

Comment: haven't used Java in years.. still edging my way along. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
List<Advantech> threads = new ArrayList<Advantech>(8);

Advantech thread;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    thread = new Advantech();
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
}
```